# Updating nested object inside react native state without manipulating whole object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, native, geojson

I am working on an react native project

Here is my state variable which i initialized inside react class component constructer

```
this.state = {
      region: {
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
      },
      markers: [],
      geoJson: null,
      geoJsonLoading: true,
      usertoken: "",
      featureChanges: null,
      socketConnectionError: "",
    };
```

Inside geoJson state variable i am storing data in below format

```
{
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    {
      userid: 'c5d84a8a-e7ec-465a-b01c-d7a9e702aed2',
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: [Object]
    },
    {
      userid: '7ccb05de-6e71-4862-b1f5-a61b134d99ef',
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: [Object]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is the shape of object the we receive on any update or newly created from server.

```
{
      userid: '7ccb05de-6e71-4862-b1f5-a61b134d99ef',
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {},
      geometry: [Object]
    }
```

Now when we receive any new or updated feature object from server, i want to add/update that feature immediately inside state and re-render the component to show updated features on MapView.

I don't want to create whole geoJson again and again because it stores many features and it can be expensive to recompute whole dataset repeatedly.I only want to perticular features that needs to be updated.

I tried many things but nothing worked. 
Please help.

Comment: what do you mean by "**I don't want to create whole geoJson again and again**", you mean a new network call?

Comment: What i want is, to first initialize geoJson with actual data when component mounts, after that i want to add/update only perticular features that we receive from continuous stream from server.

Answer (score 0):

try updating the **geoJson** when you receive a new object from server stream as shown below.

```
this.setState({geoJson:{...this.state.geoJson, features:[...this.state.geoJson.features,newObjectFromServer]})
```

Comment: Showing Error : `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'features.filter')`